# Application connection errors after phone reset

Tags: applications, connection-issues

My phone was reset, now [Wordfeud](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.hbwares.wordfeud.free) gives constant connections errors. Do I have to reset something for Wordfeud to work?

Answer (score 7):

Try going into `Settings -> Applications -> Manage Applications -> WordFeud` and clicking both the `Clear cache` and `Clear data` buttons. `Clear data` may remove your account, so you may have to log back in, but it should help the problem.

If it doesn't, I'd have to say uninstall and re-install.